# How to write link tag without Undefined function Error with phx.routes

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to write link tag to next page `xxx_path` in phoenix template.

```
<%= link to: xxx_path(@conn, :main, id) do %>
<% end %>
```

However I have following error.

```
** (CompileError) lib/xxx_web/templates/layout/header.html.eex:5: undefined function xxx_path/3
```

I tell you the `phx.routes`

```
C:\Works>mix phx.routes
  xxx_path  GET     /                               xxxWeb.XxxController :index
  xxx_path  GET     /:id                            xxxWeb.XxxController :main
```

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Show your `router.ex` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have written below.

```
<%= link to: Routes.xxx_path(@conn, :main, id) do %>
```